# Openlayers 3: add text label to feature

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have the current set up here: [fully functional fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/littleninja/yd0tdxje/6/) and whilst I have managed to zoom to each polygon feature I would also like to display a centralised text label on each... the `field_title` variable found within the `get_fields` method. I have no idea how to do this and all my googling has come up with this article: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.3.0/examples/vector-labels.html which I find totally confusing as I'm a little new to OL!

Comment: Could you move the animating part to another question? It can helps in this initial confusion.

Comment: @JonatasWalker have done. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To add a text to `ol.Feature` you will store the description in the feature and [set a style](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Feature.html#setStyle) that is a [style function](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.html#.FeatureStyleFunction) (that will get the description from the feature and show it):

```
field_polygon.set('description', field_title);
field_polygon.setStyle(styleFunction);

function styleFunction() {
  return [
    new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.4)'
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#3399CC',
        width: 1.25
      }),
      text: new ol.style.Text({
        font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: '#000' }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: '#fff', width: 2
        }),
        // get the text from the feature - `this` is ol.Feature
        // and show only under certain resolution
        text: map.getView().getZoom() > 12 ? this.get('description') : ''
      })
    })
  ];
}
```

[**Your fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/yd0tdxje/7/).

Comment: This is brilliant! Thank you! How would I only show the text above a certain zoom level?

Comment: See updated answer. `map.getView().getZoom() > 12 ? this.get('description') : ''`

Comment: are you sure this works? I'm getting `Window` on `this` instead of a `ol.Feature`

Comment: I got no a reference to `map`, so better I use a different signature for `styleFunction` : `const styleFunction = (myParams) => (feature, resulution) => . . .` then I compare the `resolution`variable instead  of  `getZoom()` to change the text content

Answer (score 3):

Since I am new here and are not allowed to comment, I put my comment as a new answer to the question of @andre_ss6. I also get `Window` on `this`. What works for me is passing in the feature object as the function's first parameter:

```
function styleFunction(feature) {
```

and then use that parameter instead of `this`:

```
text: feature.get('description')
```