# OpenLayers3. How do I add labels to lines and markers

Tags: typescript, openlayers-3

I am creating an Openlayers3 map. Unlike the examples given, I have to create  the styles for each layer before I know what the features are. I am using the following sequence:

1. Initialise the map.
2. Set up the styles for each group/ol.layer.vector

Example:

```
    this.addGroup('testPackages', {
            normalStyle: new ol.style.Style({
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: '#c407d3', width: 3, lineDash: [.1, 5] }),
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: 'rgba(196, 7, 211, 0.1)' })
            }),
            hoverStyle: new ol.style.Style({
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: '#c407d3', width: 3, lineDash: [.1, 5] }),
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: 'rgba(196, 7, 211, 0.4)' })
            }),
            selectedStyle: new ol.style.Style({
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: '#c407d3', width: 3 }),
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: 'rgba(196, 7, 211, 0.4)' })
            })

        });

    this.addGroup('cabinets', {
            normalStyle: new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Icon(({
                    scale: 0.25,
                    anchor: [0.5, 1],
                    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                    anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
                    opacity: 1,
                    src: '/images/olMaps/house.png'
                }))
            }),
            hoverStyle: new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Icon(({
                    scale: 0.25,
                    anchor: [0.5, 1],
                    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                    anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
                    opacity: 1,
                    src: '/images/olMaps/house.png'
                }))
            }),
            selectedStyle: new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Icon(({
                    scale: 0.25,
                    anchor: [0.5, 1],
                    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                    anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
                    opacity: 1,
                    src: '/images/olMaps/house.png'
                }))
            })

        })
```

3. Draw the features on the map.

Example:

```
    drawLine(geoShape: any, assetId: string, group: IAssetGroup) { // vectorLine: ol.source.Vector, style?: ol.style.Style) {

        // Transform the geometry for a map line-string.
        const transformedGeometry = this.transformCoordinates(geoShape);
        const lineString = new ol.geom.LineString(<any>transformedGeometry);

        // Create the line-string feature.
        const feature = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: lineString,
            id: assetId,
            group: group
        });

        // Set the style on the feature?
        if (!!group.normalStyle)
            feature.setStyle(group.normalStyle);

        // new lines

        var myStyle = group.normalStyle;
        myStyle = this.styleFunction(myStyle, feature);
        feature.setStyle(myStyle);

        // end


        // Add the feature to the vector-set.
        group.vector.addFeature(feature);

        // Add to list of all features.
        this.allFeatures.push(feature);
        this.lookupFeatures[assetId] = feature;

    }
```

// this is the new function that adds the text to the style

```
    styleFunction(myStyle: ol.style.Style, feature: ol.Feature) {
        return [
            new ol.style.Style({
                fill: myStyle.getFill(),
                stroke: myStyle.getStroke(),
                text: new ol.style.Text({
                    font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: '#000' }),
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: '#fff', width: 2
                    }),
                    // get the text from the feature - `this` is ol.Feature
                    // and show only under certain resolution
                    text: this.olMap.getView().getZoom() > 12 ? feature.get('name'): ''
                })
            })
        ];
    }
```

// end

```
            drawMarker(geoLocation: [number, number], assetId: string, type: string, group: IAssetGroup) {

        // Transform the geometry for a map point.
        const coordinates = this.transformCoordinates(geoLocation);
        const pointGeometry = new ol.geom.Point(<any>coordinates);

        // Create the point feature.
        const feature = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: pointGeometry,
            id: assetId,
            group: group
        });

        // Set the style on the feature?
        if (!!group.normalStyle)
            feature.setStyle(group.normalStyle);

        // Add the feature to the vector-set.
        group.vector.addFeature(feature);

        // Add to list of all features.
        this.allFeatures.push(feature);
        this.lookupFeatures[assetId] = feature;

    }
```

How do I then add the label name for each feature?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Openlayers 3: add text label to feature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39006597/openlayers-3-add-text-label-to-feature)

Comment: there is no similarity between  Openlayers 3: add text label to feature and my question. we are using completely different approaches.

Comment: Your answer is there, no matter your approach, the way to add a label is the same.

Comment: There is a line in both drawLine & drawMarker which checks the style: group.normalStyle. There may be a way of adding the label here, but I can't see how.

Comment: OK. I have added my answer to the original post.